# is there a way to do a insert an request the scope_identity() using pyodbc to sql server 2005

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have this great pyodbc lib. I try the code below, it supposed to insert a row and return the row id but it didn't work. by the way I'm using sql server 2005 on server and client is windows os

```
...
con = pyodbc.connect('conectionString', autocommit = True)
cur = con.execute(
                  "insert into sometable values('something');
                  select scope_identity() as id"
                  )
for id in cur:
   print id
...
```

some idea?

Comment: Per [this FAQs page](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs): "Use "SELECT @@IDENTITY".

Note that @@IDENTITY returns the last generated value, so if a trigger causes a 2nd insert, you'll get the trigger's generated value.

SQL Server also provides SCOPE_IDENTITY() which is supposed to fix this. Unfortunately the SQL Server ODBC driver calls an internal stored procedure for each execute call which messes up the scoping, making this unusable."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, one statement with the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(SQL.90).aspx) clause

```
cur = con.execute(
         "insert into sometable OUTPUT INSERTED.idcolumn values('something')"
         )
row = cur.fetchone()
lastrowid = row[0]
```

Edit: This should get around the issue commented by Joe S.

Comment: How to print out the value from the cur?

Comment: Updated the answer. Should be visible soon. At the end of course u can use `print(lastrowid)`

Answer (score 3):

Using [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is the way to go as there are limitations and quirks using OUTPUT and @@IDENTITY because of triggers.

Using your code snipped, you just need to add a call to [nextset](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#nextset) to get the id.

```
...
con = pyodbc.connect('conectionString', autocommit = True)
cur = con.execute(
                  "insert into sometable values('something');
                  select scope_identity() as id"
                  )
cur.nextset()
for id in cur:
   print id
...
```